# sed: match two lines and insert a line

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I've a css file with:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  src: local(Roboto Thin), url("../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Thin.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Thin.woff") format("woff");
  font-weight: 100; }
```

I'd like to add a line **only if** match the font-face line and the font-family line:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-display: swap;
  src: local(Roboto Thin), url("../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Thin.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Thin.woff") format("woff");
  font-weight: 100; }
```

I've tried something like this, but it gives me an error, unmatched `{'

```
sed '/\@font-face/{N;/  font-family\: \"Roboto\"\;/a \ \ font-display\: swap\;}' style.css   > test.txt
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
sed -e '/@font-face/{' -e n -e '/font-family: "Roboto"/a \ \ font-display: swap;' -e '}' style.css   > test.txt
```

See [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/5D1aW5):

```
s='@font-face {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  src: local(Roboto Thin), url("../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Thin.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Thin.woff") format("woff");
  font-weight: 100; }'
sed -e '/@font-face/{' -e n -e '/font-family: "Roboto"/a \ \ font-display: swap;' -e '}' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-display: swap;
  src: local(Roboto Thin), url("../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Thin.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Thin.woff") format("woff");
  font-weight: 100; }
```

**Details**

- `'/@font-face/{'` - find a line with `@font-face`, starts a block
- `n` - clears the pattern space, reads the next line into it
- `'/font-family: "Roboto"/a \ \ font-display: swap;'` - if the current pattern space (the line right below the one with `@font-face`) contains `font-family: "Roboto", append the line   `font-display: swap;`
- `'}'` - end of block.

Comment: Thanks. I've also fixed my command: sed -e '/\@font-face/{N;/  font-family\: \"Roboto\"\;/a \ \ font-display\: swap\;' -e '}' style.css   > test.txt

Comment: @Giuseppe Good, the point is that the `}` after `a` command should be separated with `-e` because otherwise, it will be considered as part of the appended line, and the block won't be "closed" correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/@font-face/!b;n;/font-family: "Roboto";/!b;p;s/family.*/display: swap;/' file
```

If a line *does not* contain `@font-face` bail out i.e. print as normal.

If a line *does* contain `@font-face`, print it and fetch the next into the pattern space and it that *does not* contain `font-family: "Roboto";`, bail out i.e. print as normal.

Otherwise, print the current line i.e. `font-family: "Roboto";` and then replace everything from `family` to the end of the line with `display: swap;`

N.B. The `b` command without a place holder, defaults to bailing out of all future sed commands. The solution below has the same result as that above.

```
sed '/@font-face/!ba;n;/font-family: "Roboto";/!ba;p;s/family.*/display: swap;/;:a' file
```